# Deleting the item next to but outbound

Tags: java

I am trying to delete item that equals specific requirements.

```
private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<>();

items.add(new Item("Movie2", "2020", "2"));
items.add(new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2"));
items.add(new Item("Movie1", "2010", "3"));
```

if  **Movie1** and **2010** were the same with another item, delete that movie.

I try with this and because there's no item after three and get arrayoutofbound exception.
Can some help me thanks.

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.size() ; i++){
    if( (items.get(i).getName().equals(items.get( i + 1).getName()) && check year)
      items.remove(items.get(i));
}
```

Expected result:

```
items.add(new Item("Movie2", "2020", "2"));
items.add(new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IndexOutOfBoundsException is triggered when a program attempts to access an an element at an index that is greater than or equal to the size of the an array (or any indexed set of elements). The problem in your code lies in the if statement inside of the for loop:

```
if( (items.get(i).getName().equals(items.get( i + 1).getName()) && check year)
```

Imagine that you have reached the last element in your traversal of the LinkedList. The above statement seeks to compare this last element with the element at the next index. Clearly, this is nonsensical; there is no next element.

The straightforward way to eliminate duplicates within some indexed list L is to have a simple nested loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < L.length; i++){
     curr_item = L[i]
     for(int j = i + 1; j < L.length; j++){
           if(L[j] == L[i])
               L[j] = null; //or some other remedy
```

Answer (score 0):

> I try with this and because there's no item after three and get
> arrayoutofbound exception.

It must be [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)), not `arrayoutofbound`. The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when the index is out of range (`index < 0 || index >= size()`). In your case, you need to terminate the loop before `items.size() -1` as you are trying to access `items.get( i + 1)`. It should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.size() - 1; i++)
```

Another problem with your approach is that you are comparing only with the immediate next element whereas the matching element can be anywhere in the list. Therefore, you need to compare the elements using nested loops i.e. an element needs to be compared with all remaining elements until a match is found and as soon as the match is found, remove the matching element and stop the process.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Objects;

class Item {
    String name, year, id;

    public Item(String name, String year, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, year, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        return this.name.equals(other.name) && this.year.equals(other.year) && this.id.equals(other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + ", Year: " + year + ", ID: " + id;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
        Item item1 = new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2");
        Item item2 = new Item("Movie2", "2020", "2");
        Item item3 = new Item("Movie2", "2020", "3");
        Item item4 = new Item("Movie1", "2010", "3");
        Item item5 = new Item("Movie2", "2020", "4");
        items.add(item1);
        items.add(item2);
        items.add(item3);
        items.add(item4);
        items.add(item5);

        System.out.println("Original list:");
        items.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        remove(items, item1);
        System.out.println("\nList after first removal:");
        items.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        remove(items, item2);
        System.out.println("\nList after second removal:");
        items.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static void remove(LinkedList<Item> items, Item item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < items.size(); j++) {
                if (items.get(i).getName().equals(items.get(j).getName())
                        && items.get(i).getYear().equals(items.get(j).getYear())) {
                    items.remove(j);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original list:
Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 2
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 3
Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 3
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 4

List after first removal:
Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 2
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 3
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 4

List after second removal:
Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 2
Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 4
```

Comment: Actually you can do simply `items.get(i).equal(items.get(j))`. This is why we are overriding `equal()` function.

Comment: @fuat - I had done it earlier using this approach (please check the edits) but then I realized that OP wants to compare only on `name` and `year`. So, I updated my answer. `Item` may have so many fields but here the comparison is required on a subset of attributes.

Comment: Even if `Item` may have so many fields, you can just simply update `equal()` function, hence all of the `if` condition will effected. So the developer do not deal with messy conditions, developers don't have to deal with remember of each condition logic. One time write, use it everywhere. That is the java mentality.

Comment: @fuat - You are missing the big picture. If you update `equals` to satisfy just one type of condition (e.g. in this case, `name` and `year` of the item) what will happen with other types of conditions e.g. when there is a requirement to compare on `year` and `id` or when there is a requirement to compare on `name` and `id` or when there is a requirement to compare on all fields?